# Call HTML Element ID on Ajax return data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem here.

I have done jQuery and Ajax, but I am not able to get the id element on my page. 
This is the code (I use Codeigniter):

```
$('#courier').change(function(e){
  var courier = $(this).val();
  var cityfrom = $('#cityfrom').val();
  var cityto = $('#cityto').val();
  var weight = $('#tot_weight').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>backend/Ctransaction/showShipType",
    data: {Courier:courier, Cityfrom:cityfrom, Cityto:cityto, Weight:weight},
    datatype:"html",
    success: function(data){
      $('#detailtype').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

My Model:

```
function showShipType(){
    $courier = $this->input->post('Courier');
    $cityfrom = $this->input->post('Cityfrom');
    $cityto = $this->input->post('Cityto');
    $weight = $this->input->post('Weight');

    $cost = $this->rajaongkir->cost($cityfrom, $cityto, $weight, $courier);

    $data= "<select class='form-control' id='typeship' name='typeship'>";

    $data1 = json_decode($cost,true);

    for($i=0;$i<count($data1['rajaongkir']['results']);$i++){

      for($j=0;$j<count($data1['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs']);$j++){
            $type = $data1['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$j]['service'];
            $price = $data1['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$j]['cost'][0]['value'];

            $data.= "<option value='$type'>$type</option>";
      }
    }

    $data.="</select>";

    echo $data;

}
```

That code will response with my div in view

```
<div id='detailtype'></div>
```

The ajax.php returns following code to div 'detailtype'

```
<select class='form-control' id='typeship' name='typeship'>
   <option></option>
   <option value='OKE'>OKE</option>
   <option value='REG'>REG</option>
   <option value='YES'>YES</option>
</select>
```

[My View Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0ZG.jpg)

The problem is:

I need to call #typeship and get the value from the dropdown to get shipping cost value.

```
$('#typeship').change(function(e){
  var courier = $('#courier').val();
  var cityfrom = $('#cityfrom').val();
  var cityto = $('#cityto').val();
  var weight = $('#tot_weight').val();
  var shiptype = $(this).val();
  alert (shiptype); // didn't response -> no alert pop up 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>backend/Ctransaction/showShipCost",
    data: {Courier:courier, Cityfrom:cityfrom, Cityto:cityto, Weight:weight, Shiptype:shiptype},
    datatype:"html",
    success: function(data){
      $('#detailcost').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

But I've tried many times to call #typeship, it seems don't response my code. 
I'm stuck, can't get the shipping cost value because of that.

I need your help to figure out my code problem.
I don't know how to resolve this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use jquery on dynamically added html without listening to changes in your html.

Use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change', '#typeship', function(e){
  var courier = $('#courier').val();
  var cityfrom = $('#cityfrom').val();
  var cityto = $('#cityto').val();
  var weight = $('#tot_weight').val();
  var shiptype = $(this).val();
  alert (shiptype); // didn't response -> no alert pop up 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>backend/Ctransaction/showShipCost",
    data: {Courier:courier, Cityfrom:cityfrom, Cityto:cityto, Weight:weight, Shiptype:shiptype},
    datatype:"html",
    success: function(data){
      $('#detailcost').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Teddy if my answer is correct and helped, you might accept it as answer and close the question.